# How do I replace part of a matrix with another smaller matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix 3000x3000x70, and I processed a small section of it separately from the main matrix. The smaller matrix is 250x250x70. How do I replace those same indices of the main matrix?

Here's what I've tried:

```
combo_matrix = main_matrix(2750:end,2750:end,:)==small_matrix
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your question you're using '==' however this is to test for equality, not to perform assignment. You can create a copy of the `main_matrix` as `combo_matrix` with the chunk replaced via the following. Note that the indices for replacement have to start at 2751 and not 2750 since you're replacing the final 250 values.

```
% create matrices with random values for demonstration
main_matrix = rand(3000, 3000, 70);
small_matrix = rand(250, 250, 70);

% to create a copy of the original main_matrix:
combo_matrix = main_matrix;
combo_matrix(2751:end,2751:end,:) = small_matrix;
```

Or overwrite the values in the original `main_matrix` via:

```
% to replace values in original main_matrix:
main_matrix(2751:end,2751:end,:) = small_matrix;
```